# rails active record exec_query SQL with join how to avade replaced id

Tags: sql, sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, left-join

I have rails project, and I have connection to second remote db  on `MSSQL` (terrible, I know - but I have to migrate old database to new one on `Postgresql`)

I config all ok, and have possibility to exec_query `SQL` queries to `MSSQL` database, but I get bad data, when I use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`
e.g.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:some_mssql).connection.exec_query('
  SELECT * FROM Members m 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MemberPhysicalInfo ph 
      ON m.idPhysicalInfo = ph.id 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Addresses ad 
      ON ph.registrationaddress = ad.id 
  WHERE (m.idphysicalinfo IS NOT NULL)
')
```

It returns all fields what i need ok, BUT in result['id'] field, I have id from table `Address` (which I join last) but not `Members` ids.

If I remove join `Address` table - in id I will get `MemberPhysicalInfo` ids, and again not a `Members` ids. And the question is - how I can avoid id  field to be replaced?

I need join, because, if I get all tables separate, then I have to:

```
addresses.select{|h| h['id'] = member[:address_id]}.first
```

And it takes ~15 minutes for transfer all data (i have >271_000 rows in members)

p.s. My english is bad, sorry - feel free to ask me for more clear explanation pls.

Comment: Do you have the key `m.id` available in the result hash?

Comment: hello, I don't know why, - cause of activerecord, or mb something else, but I have result looks like 

        `{id: , name: , etc.} `

- so I guess id replaced with id from last table, I mean something like

         `result['id'] = m.id;
         result['id'] = ph.id;
         result['id'] = ad.id;` instead of 
         ` result['m']['id'] = m.id;
           result['ph']['id'] = ph.id; `